# I cannot use variable string in my SQL query using Oracle connection

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, oracle

I have a simple code i am just trying to know if the given userid entered is already registered. So i write;

```
string a="somestring";

conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=Home-PC;Persist Security Info=True;UserID=ali;Password=abc123;");

conn.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from users where userid=@a", conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);

var data = cmd.ExecuteReader();   <--  Here it shows error *illegal variable name/number*

if (data.HasRows)   return false;
else return true;
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error? or wrong output?

Comment: @DH__ error "**illegal variable name/number**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using named parameters in an SQL statement referenced by an [OracleCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.aspx), you must precede the parameter name with a colon `(:)`.

Try changing your command text from

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from users where userid=@a", conn);
```

to

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from users where userid = :a", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":a", a);
```

and then execute you command as follows

```
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. its surprising i dint find this syntax on google. All i found was @variable-name. Any how thanks.